# URL changes but will not refresh the page

Tags: html, wordpress, url, elementor

I use a software called Bookee and they run our scheduling features. Right now the website has submenus and when you click the one it will change the url but not refresh the page. I do not know anything about coding and was told the issue was in this code. How do I fix it and can anyone explain why the url changes but doesn't refresh the page.

Here is a link to the code in the elementor system within Wordpress. https://d.pr/i/3dzf4e

```
<div id="studioyou-embed"></div>
                    <script>
                        const date = Date.now();
                        const xscript =  document.createElement("script");
```

xscript.setAttribute("src",`https://graysanatomyacademy.onbookee.com/embed/index.js?t=${date}`);
const embedContainer = document.querySelector("body");
xscript.onload = function () {new StudioYouEmbed('graysanatomyacademy.onbookee.com');};
embedContainer.appendChild(xscript);

Answer (score 0):

ayo pretty sure it's cause you never ended the script with a  Im not sure if this is all your code tho. This is a fixed version.

```
<div id="studioyou-embed"></div>
                    <script>
                        const date = Date.now();
                        const xscript =  document.createElement("script");
                        </script>
```

how did you do this without coding knowledge lol